# Extracting data from Business Central incrementally to Azure SQL

Tags: azure, dynamics-business-central

I am new to Business Central. I am very familiar with NAV.

I am building a datwarehouse and need to load the data from Business Central. I know we have to access the data via Web Service. I don't want to load all the data every time.

How can I retrieve the data incrementally?

Thanks

Comment: Is it On Premise or Cloud?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ODATA linked service in data factory to load data incrementally. Below is the detailed approach. In Sink datastore Datawarehouse, create a `watermark_table` which stores the maximum value of a source data. This is used to track the changes in the data source and to extract only the changed data during incremental data loading.

- Create a watermark table and initially insert the data as `'1900-01-01'` in it.

```sql
create table watermark_table ( watermark_column datetime2)
insert into watermark_table values  ('1900-01-01')
```

- Add a lookup activity in ADF pipeline and create a dataset for the above watermark table.

[image]

- Take a copy activity and connect sequentially with Lookup activity. Use OData as source data. Refer this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-odata?tabs=data-factory) for using OData connector.
- In Source dataset, Select *Query* option. Click *Add dynamic content*.  Enter the query as

`$filter=<column-name> gt '@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow}'`

Replace `<column-name>`  with watermark_column name.

[image]

- Add the sink connector for Synapse sql pool in copy activity. Refer this [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse?tabs=data-factory) for Synapse connector in ADF.
- Then add a script activity next to copy activity to update the watermark value with the latest value.

```sql
update watermark_table
set watermark_column=(select max(<column-name>) from <table-name>)
```

Replace `<column-name>` and `<table-name>` with the required column name and table name respectively.

When you run the pipeline, you can load data incrementally.